# Webpack fails to transpile CRA app, trying to import firebase from URL

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, create-react-app

I've got a simple create-react-app going, have `firebase` (`^9.1.1`) npm package installed, and am trying to get up and running (this is my first go with Firebase - I have no idea what I'm doing...)

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {
   ...
}

export const firestoreApp = initializeApp(config)
export const db = getFirestore(firestoreApp)
console.log(db.name)
```

When webpack works its magic, I get the following error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/firebase/firebase-firestore.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js' in '/Users/<user>/git/<project>/node_modules/firebase'
```

Looking at the file, the top has an import from a URL `import { _registerComponent, registerVersion, _getProvider, getApp, _removeServiceInstance, SDK_VERSION } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js';`

Is this normal? I've never seen an import from a URL like this (but I'm also not a native JS dev) Is this a webpack issue and I'm just a dunce? A bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, It's a bug. I had the same problem. Fixed it downgrading to the version before 9.1.1:

```
npm install firebase@9.1.0
```

Comment: I just saw the same from my support case - 9.1.2 is now out!

Comment: Just glad I wasn't actually losing my noodle! :D

Comment: All that said, neither 9.1.2 or 9.1.0 work for me - same exact issue (different URL to match version though)

Comment: Relevant bug here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3000

Comment: I realised using firebase 9 is not worth it, it still has a lot of bugs and very few solutions on the internet, since it's a major change compared to version 8. Im using version 8.10.0 and it is all working perfectly.